# Ubuntu update stops while configuring mysql-server-5.7

Tags: updates, 16.04, mysql, update-manager

When I update my Ubuntu sofwares and applications using Software Updater in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, the update stops while **Configuring mysql-server-5.7**(when the downloaded updates are being installed). And in the **Details**, I get this message :

```
   Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1) ...
   locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory 
   locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
   locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
   insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (empty) of script 'mysql' overrides LSB defaults (2 3 4 5).
   insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (0 1 2 3 4 5 6) of script 'mysql' overrides LSB defaults (0 1 6).
```

Please suggest a method to get rid of this problem.

Comment: Those are just info/warning messages, nothing to stop the update process.

Comment: That runlevel warning has convinced apt and dpkg that the package is in a broken state, for me.  This is a little frustrating; I only start mysql-server when I am actually working in a project that uses it. If that blocks updates, then maybe the path of least resistance is to just let it auto start. I have too many databases and services installed on my dev machine to let them all auto start on system start.

Comment: This warning hangs my whole system. Then I am unable to stop and cut update manager. After this warning, nothing happens. Thus, Software Updates doesn't complete.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem is that during the `mysql-server` configure process, the mysql service is restarted.
Check that you have mysql service enabled else mysql will not restart and the configuration process fails:

- Execute

  ```
  sudo update-rc.d mysql enable
  ```
- Comment 'manual' if present in mysql.override

  ```
  sudo vi /etc/init/mysql.override
  ```

Comment: I ran into something very similar when trying to upgrade from 5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 to 5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1. In my case I only got the runlevel warnings; running `sudo update-rc.d mysql enable` fixed the problem, so that I was able to complete the upgrade. The root cause: I had disabled mysql from starting at boot. Note that this worked despite the fact that I'm using `systemd`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same kind of problem. I had to log in with another session, to kill the `dpkg` process and to rerun `dpkg --configure -a` twice before it worked again. Please backup your database if you can before doing the configuration, to make sure you don't lose anything!

Comment: I tried to do this. But every time I got errors. First "dpkg" got locked.  So I tried to remove the lock and kill the "dpkg" process, but I was unable to do this even after using "sudo". Now I am getting error of unmet dependencies. I think mysql-5.7 has a lot of bugs and it has completely damaged my system, especially "dpkg".