# Not able to `sudo apt install` anything

Tags: apt, dpkg

I had been experimenting with a software called topgrade ever since then I ran into some problems on my system which was previously working fine. It started with not being able to launch vscode from the command line using `code` (even though it was installed and I could launch it by pressing the window key and looking it up) then I discovered that my apt is also broken. Whenever I tried installing anything using apt it would get stuck at

```
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.27-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (empty) of script `mysql' overrides LSB defaults (2 3 4 5).
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (0 1 2 3 4 5 6) of script `mysql' overrides LSB defaults (0 1 6).
```

So I closed the terminal in which the install was running and tried to install it in another terminal but the dpkg lock frontend error started coming up so I tried killing all the apt processes and ran the install again but the dpkg lock error still showed up so I went ahead and deleted the `lock-frontend` file still things didn't work

Did a reboot tried apt install again and I was asked to configure dpkg so I ran `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and it was again stuck at the mysql-server setup.

So I tried the solution in this post to fix the mysql-server from hanging [Ubuntu update stops while configuring mysql-server-5.7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/791304/ubuntu-update-stops-while-configuring-mysql-server-5-7)

It worked at least the mysql server doesn't hang anymore but when I ran `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and got the following log https://pastebin.com/nwcAcZW8  which now shows a `git-daemon-run` error and I get the same error when I try to run apt install

```
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]  
Setting up runit (2.1.2-3ubuntu1) ...
start: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
dpkg: error processing package runit (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of git-daemon-run:
 git-daemon-run depends on runit; however:
  Package runit is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package git-daemon-run (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 runit
 git-daemon-run
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

```
sudo apt-get purge runit
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt update
sudo apt install runit
```

So I purged runit and tried to install it again and go the following error

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fgetty runit
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 205 not upgraded.
Need to get 121 kB of archives.
After this operation, 567 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Get:1 http://it-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 fgetty amd64 0.7-1 [18.9 kB]
Get:2 http://it-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 runit amd64 2.1.2-3ubuntu1 [102 kB]
Fetched 121 kB in 1s (62.8 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package fgetty.
(Reading database ... 538427 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../fgetty_0.7-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking fgetty (0.7-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package runit.
Preparing to unpack .../runit_2.1.2-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking runit (2.1.2-3ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Setting up fgetty (0.7-1) ...
Setting up runit (2.1.2-3ubuntu1) ...
start: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
dpkg: error processing package runit (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 runit
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**Update**

I tried the solution suggested by @karel in their answer and when I executed the last command to reinstall runit I got the following error

```
start: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
dpkg: error processing package runit (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 runit
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: updated the description after trying the suggest fix in the post

Comment: No duplicate question was found for the updated question after it was edited so I posted an answer instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the `dpkg: error processing package runit (--configure):` error open the terminal and type:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a # instruct dpkg to "fix" itself
sudo apt-get -f install # correct dependencies and continue to configure your packages
sudo apt install runit --reinstall # reinstall runit
```

The above commands should get rid of the configuration errors, but now the runit package is causing a `Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused` error. It won't break any core components in Ubuntu if you uninstall runit. Forcibly remove runit by running `sudo dpkg -r runit git-daemon-run`. You might need to use one of the `--force-*` options in order to remove it.

```
sudo dpkg -r runit git-daemon-run
sudo apt autoremove
```